# wrong related articles by category

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-module

am using joomla 2.5, k2 as a content manager. am trying to display related articles by category under every k2 article. so i instaled module everywhere, create a new k2 template and finaly add this code : `<h3>Voir Aussi</h3>
    {module Related By Category|category_id=<?php echo $this->item->category->id; ?>}`
4 articles are displaying but they don't belong to the same category of the article.
here is the link for my site: [my site](http://tounes24.com/sante/ne-boirez-jamais-du-cola.html)

how can i fix it?

Comment: What happens if you replace`<?php echo $this->item->category->id; ?>` with the actual category ID?

Comment: the same problem. my categories began with 100 as id but one i replace `<?php echo $this->item->category->id; ?>` with 1 or 2 or 3, it works. module everywhere has his own ids. i think when he dones't found the category id, it displays articles from all categories. but how can i fix it?